# Postgres/Supabase RLS - Only Admin can Insert if the ID matches from another table

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I'm trying to learn Postgres RLS.

My objective: only an *admin* can insert an amenity, and it must match the id of the condo the admin already belongs too.

something like:

```
(EXISTS ( SELECT 1
   FROM condos
  WHERE (auth.uid() = condos.admin_id)))
```

This is a policy I'm adding to `public.amenitites`

But I'm getting an 403 when trying to POST. I've written it wrong and I'm not sure what to change.

Comment: have you tried to implement this using [custom claims](https://github.com/supabase-community/supabase-custom-claims)?

Comment: No I haven't. Surely my requirement is simple enough without needed any plugins.